# How can I join multiple Apps into one

Tags: android, ios

I understand this particular issue have been addressed in different forums, still I wanted to clarify.

**Problem Statement**
We're launching a solution both on Web & App. There are 3 very specific verticals which will be glued on the Web through one landing page, but will have individual sites. For the Mobile App we are planning 3 different Apps. Here's where we are facing challenge.

> 1) Customer registration is one shared across all verticals - how to achieve it
>   2) We want the same Database across all 3 verticals
>   3) How to bundle the Apps together in Android and iOS
>   4) Is it possible that if you download one of the App, rest 2 will also be downloaded
>   5) For each of the platform what should be our approach

**Strategic Question** 
Any suggestions will be really appreciated.
Is is advisable to take this approach in splitting up the Apps? I ask this from the perspective of promoting the Apps. How feasible is this.
What other approach can we adopt in segmenting the verticals, yet keeping the landing page of the App same but give a completely different user journey for all 3 verticals?

Thanks in advance.